# I need help to determine the distribution

Tags: distributions, goodness-of-fit, histogram

[image: **Histogram**]

So I have an assignment to estimate the distribution of different sets of and then make a goodfit test to see if the assumption is correct. This is my current histogram, and I have tried both exponential distribution and normal distribution but none works. The lecturer has described uniform, triangular, poisson, normal and exponential distribution so i think it should be one of those since otherwise it is impossible for us to know how to test the distribution. The measured data represents the call duration of 10,000 calls. What do you guys think?

Comment: Welcome to CV! When you say "none works," what we're the results and what were you expecting? It looks much like a gamma distribution, or among the options you mentioned, an exponential.

Comment: What do you use to check if they work? If you are doing a statistical test, are you doing that on the displayed groups (i.e. 0-29, 30-59 but 300-1000)?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: (FWIW, I don't think this thread needs to be closed.)

Comment: This is a challenging problem because no goodness-of-fit test is suitable (without some kind of adjustment) for the purpose of evaluating your choice. An appropriate GoF test would need to account for the entire set of possible distribution families you considered in your search for a fit.

Comment: To check if they work I am using CHI-square test. To chose the intervals for exponential distribution I am using integration. I.e. integration of the PDF which gives me beta*ln(1/1-i*pi), where pi is given by 1/(number of intervals). The number of intervals should be between sqrt(n) and n/5, where n=10000. Something in between would be roughly 1000 but since the chi-square test charts limits me with a degree of freedom of 100 I chose k=100. The outcome of the CHI-test is above 1000 which is not even closet to the limit which is around 150 with a significance level of 95%.